# nginx subdomain rewrite to a given url (with params)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i'm trying to setup a custom nginx rewrite rule,
in order to match a given subdomain with it's partner id route.

URL: https://subdomain.doma.com >
should display https://subdomain.domain.com/?partner=subdomain

Here is my config:

##################

```
   server {
         listen 80;
         server_name   ~^(?<subdomain>.+?)\.domain\.com$;
         root /var/www/domain.com;
         index  index.html;
 
     location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        rewrite ^ /?partner=$subdomain break;
     }
```

##################

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably mean a redirect if you want to change an URL in the browser address bar? You can't do it using internal rewrite, only HTTP 30x redirection can be used to do it.

Comment: Thanks. what im trying to achieve is to rewrite this "https://.org/?partner=ABC123" into this "https://ABC123..org".

Comment: Please use markdown formatting (backticks). Your explanation is extremely unclear. You want to process `https://subdomain.example.com` same way as `https://example.com/?route=subdomain` would be processed? What is the technology you web app is built on? According to your `location` block, it is some kind of JavaScript-based framework like React/Angular/Vue/etc?

Comment: Exactly. same way. We are using Nodejs with Angular and Fastify in the backend.

Comment: This is impossible. At least without the deep backend code modification. Your backend app will see the URL exactly as it will appear at the user browser, and you can't make it to see the additional `?route=subdomain` when it isn't there. No internal rewrite rules can help you with this, the only way is HTTP redirect (however it will change the URL at the address bar).